# Problems detecting whether cursor is still in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover

I made a variable that is assigned a value of 1 when the cursor enters a span element, ultimately retaining this value until the cursor leaves that element.

The purpose of this is to check whether the user is still hovering over that element, as I don't know of a simpler way that would bypass using the ":hover" selector.

The problem is that when I check if hovering==1 by displaying an alert, no alert is displayed when I clearly entered the element and didn't leave it.

Anyone know how to fix this?

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hmr5ui4fmK).

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top slideIn">
            <div class="container">             
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">                    
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                            
                      <li><a href = "#"><span>ELEMENT</span></a></li>                       
                    </ul><!-- END: "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" -->
                </div><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

JS:

```
var hovering=0;

$( "span" )
    .mouseover(function() {  
        hovering=1;
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        hovering=0;   
    });
if (hovering==1) {
    alert("HOVERING");
}
```

**EDIT**: My goal was essentially to check whether the user was still hovering over the element as they scrolled down the page. This code did the trick:

```
$( "span" )
    .mouseover(function() {  
        hovering=1;
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        hovering=0;   
    });

var hovering =0;
(function() {        
    var timer;
    $(window).bind('scroll',function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout( refresh , 150 );
        scrolling=true;
        if (hovering==1) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
                alert("HOVERING; NOT AT TOP");
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
                alert("HOVERING; AT TOP");
            }
        }
    });
    var refresh = function () { 
        scrolling=false;
    };
})();
```

Comment: Your `if` statement containing the alert is run right after you add the listeners onto the span. This is happening before you even have a chance to mouse over the span. What are you trying to make happen on mouse over? As an example, if you want to make the text red on mouse over, you would put the code to make it red inside the mouseover handler function, and then the code to change it back inside the mouseout handler function.

Comment: Nevermind; I got it - I see now that the way I structured this question has made it come off as very broad relative to my goal.

Comment: Updated Bootply incorporating @forgivenson comment http://www.bootply.com/a0DbMZMUXo